# How to change from non root user to non root user with ansible

Tags: ansible

I access to my host with user "admin", I can change to my applicative user : "appli" with the command :

```
# sudo su - app
```

But this task doesn't work :

```
- command: "/opt/local/application/do_something.sh"
  become_user: appli
  become_method: sudo
  remote_user: admin
```

I got an error : "sudo: a password is required".

I could deploy ssh key to authorized_keys of appli, but I would prefer to do it with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Chained become methods are not (and probably will not be) supported- you have to use either sudo or su, not both. You can specify a become password with -K if that's the only issue...